# What is the correct way to get the starting point of a Box2D body?

Tags: box2d

when I use `getPosition()` I get the center point of the body. The fixture's position in the body is relative to the body. However if the body is inclined and has an angle do I need to calculate the starting point of the body? I need this point to draw a sprite on it. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is "the starting point" of a body? Coordinates that are closest to the origin of the world? Coordinates furthest from it? Something else?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 You know when I draw something on the canvas I need to know where to put this sprite. Say if I have a rectangle I need the top left point of the rectangle. If it is a line it is the left end of the line.

Comment: You would need to rotate your sprite to be in sync with your box2d body/fixture.

Comment: @jgallant Thanks I figure out I need to anchor my sprite to its center and then rotate it to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Say that you want the vertex at `L = (-w/2, -h/2)`, where `w` is the width of the rectangle and `h` is the height. Say that your box is at point `P`, rotated of an angle `theta` with respect to the axis orthogonal to the 2D plane.

First, get `L' = R(theta) L`, using the rotation matrix `R(theta)`. This is the vector pointing at the desired corner, rotated according to the orientation of the box.
Second, translate it with `P`, so that your desired point is `X = P + L'`.